# Is there a place to temporarily hold code?

Tags: cdn

I am currently using webflow to design a site and want to add custom code that requires an upload of an ajax data txt file. I'd like to externally link the file, I'd normally upload to a personal hosting account, but I don't have one at the moment. So I am looking for a place to upload the txt file to and when you open it opens something like this [jQuery CDN](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js)

IS there such a facility available? I don't need the file to be there long, just for a few hours for testing.

Comment: have you considered github?

Comment: i didn't know it worked that way ... I'll try it.